# Beginner, Ruby embedded on html page, doesn't show up in browser?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can not the  results of database on browser when pushing it to open shift,while it works okay on my localhost machine, some one knows what is going there?

controler

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @post = Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def delete
  end
end
```

model

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :email, :text, :title
 end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>index</h1>
   <% @post.each do |p|  %>
   <br />
   <%= p.email %>
   <%= p.title %>
 <% end %>
```

out put:

```
 index

 []
```

Comment: ruby embedded code will not be displayed in the browser. erb is somthing that converts your code into browser understandable html.

Answer (score 1):

`ERB` has different kind of tags. The main ones are:

1. `<% ruby code %>`, which executes an operation in context,
2. `<%= ruby code %>`, which executes an operation in context and outputs its result,
3. `<%# anything %>`, which inserts a comment.

You typically use `2` to write things on the page, either on their own or inside a block or loop defined with `1` -- see what I meant when I said *in context*?

Your code should be:

```
<% @post.each do |p|  %>
  <br />
  <%= p.email %>
  <%= p.title %>
<% end %>
```

---

aside from that, the output you are getting, `[]`, is the result of the first operation: `<%= @post.each do |p|  %>`. It might mean that you've got an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
<%= @post.each do |p| %>
```

is wrong

Remove the "="

```
<% @post.each do |p| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use equal sign for the loop in your html page

replace this line

```
<%= @post.each do |p|  %>
```

to

```
<% @post.each do |p|  %>
```

and make sure you will have some records in your post controller otherwise 
you will get empty array like this:

```
index
[]
```