# openshift ruby can not recognize rails console?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536111/beginner-ruby-embedded-on-html-page-doesnt-show-up-in-browser)  and it runs okay in my localhost, but when I push it to open shift server it can not read the data I have added in rails controller as like title or email etc, and shows nothing, when there is no syntax error ?

Comment: `it can not read the data I have added in rails controller` - I hope you mean console?

Comment: yes I meant when I ran rails c, then inside there I can added some stuff to for my table and save it.